# I' can't compile the next program

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, compilation

I was trying to execute the following program, but I find the next error:

```
$ make install

rm -f /usr/games/install /usr/share/man/man6/greed.6
cp greed /usr/games
cp: can not perform `stat 'on' greed ': The file or directory does not exist
Makefile: 19: failure in the instructions for the 'install' objective
```

All this after installing xmlo as suggested by the readme
In the readme file it says the following:
"To install Greed, simply edit the Makefile to configure your system type"
What does this mean?

https://gitlab.com/esr/greed

I triying to perform this on ubuntu 18.04 os

Thanks!

Comment: There's no such thing as Ubuntu 18.06.  I assume you mean 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makefile doesn't list the target `greed` as a prerequisite of the target `install`.  So, you have to ask make to build it yourself before you run the `install` target:

```
make
make install
```